# Getting images length from a folder dynamically

Tags: jquery

This is my code to load images dynamically

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    imageloop();
});

var i = "1";
var n="6";

function imageloop(){

    var imgCnt =  $("<img>").attr('src', "img/" + i +".jpg").appendTo("#images").width(120).height(120);
    // $('<br/>').insertAfter('img');
     if (i==n){
     //alert('loaded');
     }
     else{
     i++;
     imageloop();
    }
 }
```

It's working fine, but I am trying to get the length of images in a folder as I don't want to hard code it. How can I do that?

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    imageloop();
});

var i = "1";
var n=$('img/').length;

function imageloop(){

    var imgCnt =  $("<img>").attr('src', "img/" + i +".jpg").appendTo("#images").width(120).height(120);
    // $('<br/>').insertAfter('img');
     if (i==n){
     //alert('loaded');
     }
     else{
     i++;
     imageloop();
    }
 }
```

This code is not working

Comment: Be specific, are you trying to get the dimensions of the images you are appending or you want to append images with specific dimensions

Comment: This sounds like you want javascript to find out how many images exist in the directory on server....you need a server side script to count them. There is no way to do that from the browser. Question is not clear at all and broken code is not a good substitute for a proper explanation. Take a few minutes to read [ask]

Comment: @Rahul There are totally 6 images in my img folder.i want to append all images ,but i should not mention no.of images(n=6).Directly i need to append all imgaes. Because i may add some extra images, each time i need not change `n` value. That is why i am asking other way to do it.

Comment: Still not clear, what you really want to achieve

Answer (score 0):

You can use PHP solution to get the all images from a folder using the glob() function you can specify which file extensions your are interested in and then loop through those.

```
<?php 
$files = glob("img/*.jpg");
foreach($files as $jpg){
    echo $jpg, "\n";
}
?>
```

To transfer this to your case all you need to know if the length of how many images are in the folder, you can add something like following

```
var n=<?php $files = glob("img/*.jpg"); echo count($files);?>
```